# Why do I get a better match on mitoSearch than FamilyTreeDNA?

Tags: dna, familytreedna.com, mitochondrial-dna, mitosearch.org

For my cousin's mtDNA test (C52RJ) on FamilyTreeDNA, my closest matches are all 2 mutations away, I exported to mitoSearch, and there I find an exact match with TXANE, and the match shows as coming from FamilyTreeDNA.  Does this mean FamilyTreeDNA did not export all the data to mitoSearch?  Why else would this occur?